# Typedef pointer to an array of another typedef

Tags: c, typedef

I will like to declare a typedef, something like this:

- Pointer to any array of another typedef.

for e.g.:

Typedef 1:

```
typedef struct
{
    int a;
}structA_t1;
```

Typedef 2:

```
typedef ptrstructA  structA_t1 (*Temp)[]  ;
```

Is this second typedef correct ? Do i really need this Temp name here ? Please suggest, thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be typedef structA_t1 (*ptrstruct)[]; or somethin

Comment: Why do you want to make a typedef like that? It's commonly considered poor form to create typedefs that hide that fact that something's a pointer.

Answer (score 7):

The name of the newly defined type comes in the end:

```
typedef structA_t1 **ptrstructA;
```

or:

```
typedef structA_t1 (*ptrstructA)[];
```

Comment: More specifically, it replaces the variable name that would be there if it weren't a typedef.